# Error in Earthquake Report App

Tags: java

I am building an earthquake report app and getting this error. I searched all over Google + Stack OverFlow + udacity forums still didn't find the answer.

the error says String can't be converted into int .But I have used the exact code as mentioned in udacity.

[image: [1]]

The error says:

> ```
> getMagnitudeColor(int) in EarthquakeAdapter cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
> ```

Comment: Please post the error as text, not a link to a picture. it's saying that `currentEarthquake.getMagnitude` is a `String`, so you can't call a method expecting an `int` with it.

Comment: getMagnitudeColor(int) in EarthquakeAdapter cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

How to convert String to int ? 
If i use Interger parse, it gives me an error ..

Comment: Please edit the question instead of putting information essential to the problem in a comment.

Comment: Please include the code that generates the error. Questions must be self-contained and contain all the information necessary to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possibly because the JSON element that you are referencing has the number as a String datatype rather than an Integer? If so, you can fix it with the following:

```
int magnitudeColor = getMagnitudeColor(Integer.parseInt(currentEarthquake.getMagnitude());
```

Comment: I used this technique. 
The error now says 
Found :- double
Required :- int

Comment: @SavneetKaur ... So you're passing a double, and the method expects an int. Change one or the other.

Comment: and now , I changed it from double to int now the error says :-   GradientDrawable magnitudeCircle =  (GradientDrawable) magnitudeView.getBackground();  is unreachable

Comment: @SavneetKaur That's a new question, which should include the code and error message. But SO isn't really a great place to play whack-a-bug; it's not a tutorial site.

Comment: Okay. Anyways, Thanks. :(

Answer (score 1):

The error I was getting was due to the return statement that I had placed above GradientDrawable.
also,thanks Kevin Lee for parse method.Helped me :) 
and Dave Newton , please dont be rude while answering questions. 
I am very new to programming as well stack overflow site. 
This was my first question and i didnt think much of regulations on how should i post my Question. anyways, Ty to you. !!

Answer (score 0):

Your `getMagnitude()` method returns a string. However, your `getMagnitudeColor()` method expects an integer for a parameter. You have to either change the return type of `getMagnitude()` or change the type of your parameter for `getMagnitudeColor()` so that they both match.